# Check if provided locale exist or not

Tags: java, locale, resourcebundle

I need to set some default locale if provided locale does not exist. 
But i am not getting, how to check if a locale exist or not.

Suppose i pass `locale:xyz`, than how to check that `locale xyz` exist or not.

please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

What is `xyz`; is it a language code, country code or some other identifier for a locale?

You could call `java.util.Locale.getAvailableLocales()` to get the list of locales supported by the JVM that your program is running on, and do an appropriate comparison to find out if the locale that you're looking for is in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(!"US".equals(Locale.getDefault().getCountry())){
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    }

    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

If not US locale it will set it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `locale.getISO3Language();` method.
If it throws a `MissingResourceException`, the locale is not available, otherwise all works fine.

```
    final Locale locale = new Locale("xx");
    try {
        locale.getISO3Language();
    } catch (final MissingResourceException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid locale.");
    }
```

Comment: I tried this with new Locale("xyz"), and it did not throw an Exception - though I can find no language for which "xyz" would be the ISO code, and nothing the like shows up among Locale.getAvailableLocales()

Comment: Found it: This is because getISO3Language() just returs the language without checking for ISO codes if it has length 3. Can't use your approach for those, then.